# How to customization redirection in laravel jetstream

Tags: laravel, laravel-jetstream

i run the laravel jetstream and set to livewire not vue . i usually using auth ui and custom the login in

> App -> Http -> controller -> auth -> LoginController

in this LoginController i custom this redirect like this

```
 protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
{
    if ( $user->isUser() ) {// do your margic here
        return redirect()->route('user_dashboard');
    }
    elseif ($user->isSarpras()) {
        return redirect()->route('admin_sarpras_dashboard');
    }
}
```

but on laravel jetstream iam cant found Controller->auth . how to do best manage login and create multiple login using laravel jetstream ?

Comment: did any of the answers solve your problem? if so please mark them as accepted.

Answer (score 3):

**Jetstream** uses **Fortify** to power authentication.

Currently, Fortify doesn't have a way to customize redirects.

There is an open issue requesting this bahavior here: https://github.com/laravel/fortify/issues/77

There is a good chance this will be added soon!

**Edit**

Now you can customize the redirects via `config/fortify.php`:

```php
'redirects' => [
    'login' => 'dashboard',
    'logout' => 'home',
    'password-confirmation' => null,
    'register' => 'dashboard',
    'email-verification' => null,
    'password-reset' => null,
],
```

If you need advanced customization of this behavior check out the [docs here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/fortify#customizing-authentication-redirects).

Comment: apparently, yes.

Comment: Looks like this has been added now: https://github.com/laravel/fortify/pull/298

Answer (score 2):

Found here: https://talltips.novate.co.uk/laravel/laravel-8-conditional-login-redirects

1. Create a folder under app\Http called Responses
2. Create a file LoginResponse.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Responses;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Laravel\Fortify\Contracts\LoginResponse as LoginResponseContract;

class LoginResponse implements LoginResponseContract
{

    public function toResponse($request)
    {
        
        // below is the existing response
        // replace this with your own code
        // the user can be located with Auth facade
        
        return $request->wantsJson()
                    ? response()->json(['two_factor' => false])
                    : redirect()->intended(config('fortify.home'));
    }

}
```

3. Make Laravel use our new Response Class

This new class now replaces the Singleton previously registered by Fortify.

Edit the JetstreamServiceProvider in your app\Providers folder;

In the boot method, add reference to your new response class. When login completes (and the user is actually Authenticated) then your new response will be called.

```
    public function boot()
    {
        $this->configurePermissions();

        Jetstream::deleteUsersUsing(DeleteUser::class);

        // register new LoginResponse
        $this->app->singleton(
            \Laravel\Fortify\Contracts\LoginResponse::class,
            \App\Http\Responses\LoginResponse::class
        );
    }
```

**Two Factor Authentication**

If you use 2FA with Jetstream, you will also need to catch the TwoFactorLoginResponse.  Use the same approach;

```
        // register new TwofactorLoginResponse
        $this->app->singleton(
            \Laravel\Fortify\Contracts\TwoFactorLoginResponse::class,
            \App\Http\Responses\LoginResponse::class
        );
```

You can return the same response, or create an additional response if you want different behaviour for users that login using 2FA.